# Convert/Send Standalone EPUB from PC to Kindle via Menu/Command Line

Tags: kindle, epub, calibre, windows

I have a number of EPUBs that I manage manually i.e. they are not in a Calibre library. These are in a Google Drive folder so Calibre is simply not an option.

I'd like an easy way to convert these EPUBs to MOBI and send them to Kindle via USB, on demand. This functionality is present in Calibre and it seems to me these should not be tied to the Calibre UI; so is there a way to do this via a script or something?

If this is a tall order, just conversion is still fine, I can manually drop the files in the Kindle after mounting it via USB.

I'm working with Windows 10 64-bit and a brand new Kindle Paperwhite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the Calibre ebook-convert command line utility. The following simple batch file should do the trick:

```
FOR %%f IN ("*.epub") DO (ebook-convert "%%~nf.epub" "%%~nf.azw3")
FOR %%f IN ("*.azw3") DO (copy "%%f" "E:\documents")
```

(The script assumes that your Kindle is mounted as the E: drive; change the drive letter if it isn't the E: drive.)

Copy the two lines to a text file, save it with a .cmd or .bat extension in the same folder as the .epub files and then double-click it.